# Output Checkbox Data on Template

Tags: templating, permissions

If you have a `checkbox`  field on an entry type, how do you display all the selected values for an entry in a template with twig?

Using this for page permissions via user groups. We have a plugin that adds a new field type "user groups". It lists all groups (which we have many) on the admin page of each entry. We want to check which groups will have access and then limit the page to users in that group only.

edit: not using a standard checkbox field but a new field (via plugin). https://github.com/quebecstudio/usergroupfield

Answer (score 1):

You get all available options with the `options` attribute and you can check if it is selected in the current entry with `option.selected`

```
{% for opt in entry.checkboxFieldHandle.options %}
    <label>
        <input name="fields[checkboxFieldHandle][]" type="checkbox" value="{{ opt.value }}">
        {{ opt.label }}
        {% if opt.selected %}
            I'm selected
        {% endif %}
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

But to be honest I don't really understand your second part

**Edit**
As for your field, you can display all the selected values with

```
{% set selectedUserGroupIds = entry.userGroupFieldHandle %}
{% for userGroupId in selectedUserGroupIds %}
    {% set usergroup = craft.userGroups.getGroupById(userGroupId) %}
    {{ usergroup.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Maybe it's the field I'm using but that standard methodology is not working. I am using this plugin:
https://github.com/quebecstudio/usergroupfield

It creates a new field called usergroups and when added to a "section" it shows all the user groups in the system with empty checkboxes beside each. Hoping to use this to create very flexible page permissions (i.e. edit entry 1 and assign user group A,B, and F, then only users in groups A,B or F can access this page).

Comment: Yes you can do this with the plugin. But you don't need to display the selected values in your frontend to achieve that.

Comment: Hi Robin, was trying to display the values selected as a visual check to make sure it was grabbing the right data.

There's not a ton of documentation around that plugin so I'm not sure exactly how to get it working as desired.

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure what you want... `entry.userGroupFieldHandle` contains an array with all selected usergroup ids and an empty string if nothing was selected. You can check if it is not empty, loop through the results and get the selected group by id

Comment: I did get the id's to display, but not sure how to translate that into giving permissions. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should start to explain what you want properly. You said you want to display the selected values in your field. So all user groups now you say you want to create a form to change user permissions.